# how to upload/install python application in web server

Tags: python, apache

I have a facial recognition model created using python and wish to upload it to my cloud web server, for use within my existing website.

However, I have no idea to go about it. Is the Flask the way to go?

My server is Apache with PHP.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

GoDaddy has some documentation about this

[Python on server](https://www.godaddy.com/garage/how-to-install-and-configure-python-on-a-hosted-server/)